# Looks like Laravel valet is starting two nginx processes

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I have tried most things now so I'm desperate for some help. I have tried to reinstall laravel valet. I have also tried to reinstall brew but I keep getting the same error.

When I run `brew services list` I get:

```
▶ brew services list
Name    Status  User Plist
dnsmasq unknown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
nginx   error   root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php     started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
```

As you can see there is an error on nginx. When I run `sudo /usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx -g 'daemon off;'` I get this output:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

so it looks like there is another nginx process started somehow? When I run `sudo lsof -i tcp:80` I get this:

```
▶ sudo lsof -i tcp:80
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   71557   root    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71558 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71559 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71560 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71561 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71562 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71563 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71564 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71565 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71567 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71568 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71569 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
nginx   71571 margul    6u  IPv4 0xb2e487bcf1edb7ad      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
```

If I'm doing `ps aux | grep "nginx"` I get this:

```
▶ ps aux | grep "nginx"
margul           71571   0,0  0,0  4319864   1352   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71569   0,0  0,0  4314744   1368   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71568   0,0  0,0  4333176   1420   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71567   0,0  0,0  4313720   1340   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71565   0,0  0,0  4315768   1408   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71564   0,0  0,0  4325252   2024   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71563   0,0  0,0  4331128   1396   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71562   0,0  0,0  4331128   1360   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71561   0,0  0,0  4313720   1372   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71560   0,0  0,0  4321912   1388   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71559   0,0  0,0  4330104   1380   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
margul           71558   0,0  0,0  4320888   1408   ??  S    11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
root             71557   0,0  0,0  4293560    612   ??  Ss   11:21pm   0:00.00 nginx: master process nginx
margul           97215   0,0  0,0  4277664    752 s001  R+   12:11am   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox nginx
```

I have run out of things to try and I'm close to reinstalling MacOS which would be crazy just to get Laravel valet to work. Like I said I have tried to uninstall Laravel valet in all different ways multiple times, rebooting, stopping the nginx services, uninstalling brew.

Please if someone can point me in the right direction that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by updating [xcode](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/) (When running `brew doctor` make sure it says "Ready to brew"). Then I removed uninstalled brew using the command `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"`. Then I removed everything in `/usr/local` by doing `sudo -rf /usr/local/*` to make sure that I had removed everything from brew.

When this was done I reinstalled brew with the new xcode up to date and then reinstalled laravel valet again and it worked. When I run `brew services list` it still says error on nginx but it's working now.

```
▶ brew services list
Name    Status  User Plist
dnsmasq unknown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
nginx   error   root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php     started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
```

Comment: run ``valet restart`` once.

Comment: That did not work @OMiShah. Tried it multiple times. It must have been something that broke quite considerably because after removing everything it started to work again.